# Transformar UTF-8 para Unicode no EchoLink

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, unicode, utf8-decode

No arquivo de configuração do EchoLink Server

```
/etc/svxlink/svxlink.d/ModuleEchoLink.conf
```

nós podemos inserir a localização da estação de rádio na variável LOCATION.

Como o nome da minha cidade (Petrópolis) tem acento, sempre que eu escrevo corretamente o nome no arquivo de configuração, ele aparece modificado no EchoLink App (Client) da seguinte forma:

```
PetrÃ³polis
```

Ao que tudo indica trata-se do eterno problema entre Unicode e UTF-8.

Eu utilizei o seguinte site para tentar converter de tal forma que o "ó" aparecesse da forma correta: https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter

E de fato, quando eu escrevo Petrópolis na área de texto "UFT-8 text" aparece o seguinte resultado na área de texto "Unicode text": **Petris**.

Entretanto, na hora que eu seleciono e copio o texto unicode, alguma coisa se modifica, pois ao colar o texto copiado (Ctrl + C) no arquivo de configuração e reiniciar o servidor, vemos que no cliente **PetrÃ³polis** se transforma em algo como **Petró[][][]polis**. Ou seja, algo acontece na direção que queremos tomar (o acento aparece), mas ainda assim não está 100% correto.

Alguma dica de como resolver esse problema?
E além disso, como se chamam esses quadradinhos codificados () que aparecem no conversor online? Sabendo o nome, poderei continuar pesquisando a respeito.

Obrigado!

Comment: Que eu saiba UNICODE é um padrão teórico e possui diversas implementações, uma delas é o UTF-8 (8-bit Unicode Transformation Format), portanto não tem sentido falar em "transformar UTF-8 para Unicode). Provavelmente está ocoorendo uma especificação errônea do encoding efetivamente utilizado.

Comment: Então como entender todas essas possibilidades online de conversão de unicode em decimal, text, url, etc como o site supracitado?

Comment: Normalmente este tipo de erro ocorre quando você configura que o padrão utilizado é UTF-8 mas envia texto em outra codificação, por exemplo LATIN1 ou ISO-8859-1. Configure seu ambiente adequadamente e garanta que os caracteres estão efetivamente codificados no padrão no qual você afirma que estão. Note que isto não acontece com os caracteres da tabela ASCII pois os 127 primeiros caracteres do padrão UTF-8 são exatamente iguais aos da tabela ASCII.

Comment: O problema é que não há como eu configurar o ambiente de um software fechado. Por isso estou tentando inserir o valor da variável do arquivo de configuração do servidor (svxlink-server) já com a codificação que ele usa no cliente (app de celular).